# Add several attributes that are connected to another attribute

Tags: c#, database

I'm working on a method where I'm trying to add several attributes that are connected to a specific attribute.

The specific attribute is `staffToD.StaffId` and the name of the other several attributes I try to add is `staffToD.DepartmentId`. I've been able to add one `DepartmentId` to one `StaffId` but when I try to add several `DepartmentId` to one `StaffId`, I'm not able to do so.

Currently both attributes are added from another method which resides in another class.

The full code is:

```
public ConnectionController DC = new ConnectionController();
public bool WorkInAdmin { get; set; }
public bool WorkInDev { get; set; }
public bool WorkInSales { get; set; }
public bool WorkInOps { get; set; }

public void AddStaff(string staffSocialSecNumber, string sName, double sWage, double staffDegreeOfEmp, double sStaffVakancy, double sAdminWork, double sSalesWork, double sOperationWork, double sDevWork, double sArsArbete, double sAllocatingControll, bool sLockStaff)
{ 
    try
    {
        Staff newStaff = new Staff();

        newStaff.StaffId = 0;
        newStaff.StaffSocialSecNumber = staffSocialSecNumber;
        newStaff.StaffName = sName;
        newStaff.StaffWage = sWage;
        newStaff.StaffDegreeOfEmp = staffDegreeOfEmp;
        newStaff.StaffVakancy = sStaffVakancy;
        newStaff.AllocatingControll = sAllocatingControll;
        double wT = staffDegreeOfEmp - sStaffVakancy;
        newStaff.WorkingTime = wT;
        newStaff.AdminWork = sAdminWork;

        if (sAdminWork != 0)
        {
            newStaff.WorkInAdmin = true;
            WorkInAdmin = true;
        }

        newStaff.DevWork = sDevWork;

        if (sDevWork != 0)
        {
            newStaff.WorkInDev = true;
            WorkInDev = true;
        }

        newStaff.SalesWork = sSalesWork;

        if (sSalesWork != 0)
        {
            newStaff.WorkInSales = true;
            WorkInSales = true;
        }
               
        newStaff.OperationWork = sOperationWork;

        if (sOperationWork != 0)
        {
            newStaff.WorkInOps = true;
            WorkInOps = true;
        }

        CC.NewCalcStaffWageByDep(sAdminWork, sDevWork, sSalesWork, sOperationWork,wT,sWage);
        newStaff.YearlyWork = 0;   // Need to be added
        newStaff.AdminWage = CC.NewAdminStaffWage;
        newStaff.DevWage = CC.NewDevStaffWage;
        newStaff.SalesWage = CC.NewSalesStaffWage;
        newStaff.OpsWage = CC.NewOpStaffWage;

        IT_ServiceController.Instance.Context.StaffRepository.Add(newStaff);
        IT_ServiceController.Instance.Save();

        DC.AddToStaffDepartment(staffSocialSecNumber, WorkInAdmin, WorkInDev, WorkInSales, WorkInOps);
```

and then added to

```
public void AddToStaffDepartment(string staffSocialSec, bool wA, bool wD, bool wS, bool wO)
{
    IEnumerable<Staff> staffs = IT_ServiceController.Instance.Context.StaffRepository.GetAll();
    Staff newStaffToDep = staffs.Where(i => i.StaffSocialSecNumber.Equals(staffSocialSec)).FirstOrDefault();

    StaffDepartment staffToD = new StaffDepartment();
    staffToD.StaffId = newStaffToDep.StaffId;

    if (wA = true)
    {
        staffToD.DepartmentId = 3;
    }
    else if (wD = true)
    {
        staffToD.DepartmentId = 1;
    }
    else if (wS = true)
    {
        staffToD.DepartmentId = 4;
    }
    else if (wO = true)
    {
        staffToD.DepartmentId = 2;
    }

    IT_ServiceController.Instance.Context.StaffDepartmentRepository.Add(staffToD);
IT_ServiceController.Instance.Save();
```

The model is

```
    public class StaffDepartment
    {
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public Staff Staff { get; set; }
    
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

The modelbuilder is

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<StaffDepartment>().HasKey(sd => new { sd.StaffId, sd.DepartmentId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<StaffDepartment>().HasOne<Staff>(sd => sd.Staff).WithMany(b => b.StaffDepartments).HasForeignKey(sd => sd.StaffId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<StaffDepartment>().HasOne<Department>(sd => sd.Department).WithMany(b => b.StaffDepartments).HasForeignKey(sd => sd.DepartmentId);
```

I'm also include a picture of the result from the database. The one of interests is those with staffId 1002 and 1003. 1003 is the one where I tried to add several DepartmentIds

[Picture from database showing both the result of adding one DepartmentId as well as adding several DepartmentIds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dhkw.png)

Comment: are you using foreign keys in your database?

Comment: The class itself is a combination of two diffrent classes and was as far as I understand needed to connect it through the database as Im using Entity Framework Core 2.2.6. I've updated my original post to include the class and the modelbuilder in the context class.